# Directory does not currently exist, the installation process will attempt to create it

Tags: javascript, php, css, cgi, moodle

When I am trying to install moodle in ispconfig I faced the following problem in the images below please i want help???

The warning:
[image: []

Error:

[image]

Comment: search: `moodle basedir in effect` it will yield solutions

Comment: You do not have permissions to install moodle in the current directory. `sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/clients/client13/web25` should solve the problem

Comment: @Chilarai that would make the folder accessible for other users on the host, which is not ideal